# What is the meaning of this portion in Rails Datetime column?

Tags: datetime, ruby-on-rails-3.2

There is something in my view:

```
<%= debug @some_object %>
and the created_at field is shown as:
2012-01-30 03:16:37.996099000Z
```

So what is the meaning of the portion of `.996099000Z`???

I am using Rails 3.2 if it matters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final portion of the datetime is microseconds.

Comment: so what we normally see `16:37.996` with higher precisions?